# foreign keys mysql and phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm developing a website with php + mysql(phpMyAdmin).

I got 2 tables: USERS and FOLLOWERS like in the link i've pasted here below:

[image]

These tables are created with a sql script that I paste here bellow:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `FOLLOWERS`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `FOLLOWERS` (
  `Follower1_Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Follower2_Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Follower1_Id`, `Follower2_Id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

(I just paste the table "FOLLOWERS" due to in that table is where is the problem).

Due to i don't know why phpMyAdmin doesn't allow to insert foreign keys, the problem comes when i try to insert a follower based on the USERS table. For any reason i can insert the user nº5 when i only have 3 users and these users have 1,2,3 as a User_Id PK.

Apparently I used the relational mode that phpMyAdmin offers me but there's no result.

What can i do?

Comment: Why do you need to set the followerid's as PK? Try making them a regular column and then create foreign keys on the FOLLOWERS table pointed to the userid of USERS table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table you created is an MyISAM table and unfortunately they don't support Foreign Keys.

http://www.sitepoint.com/mysql-myisam-table-pros-con/

In PHPMyAdmin you can easily convert it from an MyISAM to an InnoDB table. This should enable the foreign Key features you're after.

Comment: thanks, I found the error, now i can add sentences like CONSTRAINT `constraint_name` FOREIGN KEY (`foreign_key`) REFERENCES `REFERENCED_TABLE` (`referenced_constraint`);. +1

Answer (score 1):

When you say :

> phpMyAdmin doesn't allow to insert foreign keys, the problem comes
>   when i try to insert a follower based on the USERS table.

What type of error do you get?
Could you give us more information?

Comment: I solved the problem with the MyISAM to InnoDB change as Wireblue purposed me. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

`MyISAM` table doesn't support Foreignkey and it only supports Primary key. But you can convert it into `InnoDB` table and then you can assign Foreign key to it.

Comment: is it possible that a hosting doesn't support InnoDB? I have 2 hosts, 1and1 and hostinger and even thought i've been keeping an eye for a long time, the options i have is MyISAM, MRG_MyISAM, CSV, MEMORY.